# SqlLiteDatabase

Tags: android, database

Hi everyone I am trying to add the information to the database but I get an runtime error. I am pretty new to android and database. If someone can help it would be great as this is a homework and I have been stuck.

```
public class Home extends MenuActivity {

        static int counter = 0;
        String url;
        String date;
        String content;
        int countMe = 0;
        int i = 0;
        StringBuilder sb;
        List<String> str;
        List<WebPage> pages = new ArrayList<WebPage>();
        long myDate;

        DatabaseHandler dh;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home);


            regularExpresionStrings();

            dh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    //      dh.addWarrior(new Warrior(1, "Kenobi", "high", 50 , 30, "kenobi"));

            dh.addWebPage(pages);

            Cursor cursor = dh.getAllAsCursor();

            String[] cols = new String[] {DatabaseHandler.url};
            int[] to = new int[] {R.id.imageView2};

    //        sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.home, cursor, cols, to, 2);
            //new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, from, to, flags)
    //        mainListView.setAdapter(sca);  


        }

        /**
         * When this method is called we try to find a file in the sandbox area that
         * matches the DDMMYY extracted from the picker.
         * 
         * @param filename the name of the file (built using the DatePicker info)
         * @return the content of the file, or an error message if not found
         */
        private String load() 
        {
            try
            {
                Log.d("Home", " in the load method");

    //          final FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
                final InputStream fis =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pages);
                final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                fis.close();
                return sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return "No entry exists for this file";
            }
        }


        private String regularExpresionStrings()
        {

            Log.d("Home222", " in the regularExpresionStrings method");
            String content = load();

            String[] parts = content.split("</html>");
            String pa = "";
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

            for(int i=0; i<parts.length; i++)
            {
                pa = new String(parts[i] + "</html>");
                Log.d("Page" + (i + 1), pa);

                if(pa.contains("Address:"))
                {

                        url = pa.substring(pa.indexOf("http"), pa.indexOf("html") + 4);
                        Log.d("Address" + (i + 1), url);
                        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                        Editor ed = prefs.edit();
                        ed.putString("URL", url);
                        ed.commit();


    //                  getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("URL ", url).commit();
                }

                if(pa.contains("Date:"))
                {
                    date = pa.substring(pa.indexOf("Date:") + 5, pa.indexOf("Date:") + 18);
                    myDate = Long.parseLong(date);
                    Log.d("Date" + (i + 1), date);

                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                    Editor ed = prefs.edit();
                    ed.putString("Date", myDate + "");
                    ed.commit();
    //              getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("Date ", myDate + "").commit();
                }

                content = pa.substring(pa.indexOf("<!DOCTYPE html>"), pa.indexOf("</html>")) + "</html>";
                Log.d("Content" + (i + 1), content);

                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                Editor ed = prefs.edit();
                ed.putString("Content", content);
                ed.commit();
    //          getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("Content ", content).commit();


                WebPage webPages = new WebPage(i++, url, content, myDate);
                pages.add(webPages);

            }
            Log.d("WebOff","File successfully imported");
            return content;
        }
    }

public class WebPage {

    /**
     * id represent the id of the table.
     */
    private int id;

    /**
     * url represent the url of the web page.
     */
    private String url;



    /**
     * source represent the source of the web page.
     */
    private String source;

    /**
     * date represent a date
     */
    private long date;


    public WebPage() {

    }


    /**
     * WebPage() creates a web page object
     * @param url set the current url with the passed one.
     * @param source set the current source with the passed one.
     * @param date set the current date with the passed one.
     */
    public WebPage(int id, String url, String source, long date) {
        this.url = url;
        this.source = source;
        this.date = date;
        Log.d("WebOff", "WebPage object created");
    }


    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

//  /**
//   * @param id the id to set
//   */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * getUrl() gets the url of the web page.
     * @return the url
     */
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * setUrl() sets the url of the web page.
     * @param url  to set
     */
    public void setUrl(String url) {

        this.url = url;
    }



    /**
     * getSource() gets the source fo the web page.
     * @return the source
     */
    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    /**
     * setSource() sets the source of the web page.
     * @param source to set
     */
    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    /**
     * getDate() gets the date.
     * @return the date
     */
    public long getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * setDate() sets the date.
     * @param date to set
     */
    public void setDate(long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


    public void webPage() {
        Log.d("Debug","" + this.url);
        Log.d("Debug", this.source);
        Log.d("Debug", this.date + "");
    }


}


public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    /**
     * The name of the database
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WebOff.db";

    /**
     * The name of the (only) table.
     */
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "pages";

    /**
     * The name of the first column (ID)
     */
    static final int _id = 0;

    /**
     * The name of the second column (url)
     */
    static final String url = "url";

    /**
     * The name of the third column (source)
     */
    static final String source = "source";


    static final int date = 0;


//  attack

    /**
     * A constructor which builds a DatabaseHandler object. Note that calling
     * the constructor does not create a database. This does not happen until
     * the first call to getReadableDatabase() or getWriteableDatabase()
     * 
     * @param context
     *            In this case, a reference to WarriorActivity
     */
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the database is created for the first time.
     * This is where the creation of tables and the initial population of the
     * tables should happen.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + _id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
                + url + " URL,"
                + source + " Source, " 
                + date + " Date" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
        Log.d("WebOff", "Database created successful");
    }

    /**
     * Called when the database needs to be upgraded. Only relevant when you
     * have multiple versions of the database scheme in play.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldNum, int newNum) {
        // Drop older table if exist and create fresh
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to add a Warrior to the database.
     * 
     * @param Warrior
     *            the Warrior you want to add
     */
    public void addWebPage(List<WebPage> webPage) {


        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();



//      for(int i=0; i<webPage.size(); i++)
//      {
//          // Iterate through the list, adding the information stored within the WebPage object to the databese.
//          values.put("text", webPage.indexOf(i));
//      }
//      values.put(_id + "", webPage.getId());
//      values.put(url, webPage.getUrl());
//      values.put(source, webPage.getSource());
//      values.put(date +"", webPage.getDate() +"");
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();

        Log.d("WebOff", "Database populated");
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to get all of the Warriors in the database.
     * 
     * @return a list of Warrior objects, one per row
     */
    public List<WebPage> getAll() {
        List<WebPage> list = new ArrayList<WebPage>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                WebPage webPage = new WebPage(cursor.getInt(0),
                        cursor.getString(1), 
                        cursor.getString(2),
                        cursor.getInt(3));
                list.add(webPage);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return list;
    }


    /**
     * Use this method to get a Cursor object that points at all the Warriors in 
     * the database
     * 
     * @return a Cursor object pointing at all Warriors in db
     */
    public Cursor getAllAsCursor() {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        //db.close();
        return cursor;
    }


    /**
     * Use this method to remove all of the Warriors from the database. This is
     * useful when experimenting. After dropping all tables, the initial state
     * of the database is re-created.
     */
    public void removeAll() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * This method removes one WebPage from the database.
     * 
     * @param WebPage
     *            the WebPage to remove
     */
    public void deleteWebPage(WebPage webPage) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _id + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(webPage.getId()) });
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method updates the data stored in the database for one Warrior.
     * 
     * @param Warrior
     *            the Warrior to update
     * @return the number of rows affected
     */
    public int updateWebPage(WebPage webPage) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(_id + "", webPage.getId());
        values.put(url, webPage.getUrl());
        values.put(source, webPage.getSource());
        values.put(date + "", webPage.getDate());

        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, _id + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(webPage.getId()) });
    }

    /**
     * This method gets a single WebPage from the database, using the ID field
     * as a key
     * 
     * @param id
     *            the ID of the WebPage we want
     * @return a Warrior object
     */
    public WebPage getWebPage(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { _id + "", url,
                source, date + "" }, _id + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        WebPage webPage = new WebPage(Integer.parseInt(null, 
                cursor.getInt(0)),
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getInt(3));
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return webPage;
    }

    public WebPage getWebPageByName(String name){
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + _id + " =  '" +  name + "'";
        Log.d("Debug WebPage name: ", selectQuery);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        WebPage webPage = null;
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            webPage = new WebPage(cursor.getInt(0), 
                    cursor.getString(1),
                    cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getInt(3));
        }
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return webPage;
    }

}
```

when I run it i get this:

```
01-05 17:24:19.594: E/Database(1524): Failure 1 (near "0": syntax error) on 0x2465e0 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE pages(0 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,url URL,source Source, 0 Date)'.
01-05 17:24:19.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.ac.tees.L1087591/uk.ac.tees.L1087591.Home}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "0": syntax error: CREATE TABLE pages(0 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,url URL,source Source, 0 Date)
01-05 17:24:19.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1524): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "0": syntax error: CREATE TABLE pages(0 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,url URL,source Source, 0 Date)
01-05 17:24:19.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
01-05 17:24:19.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1727)
01-05 17:24:19.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at uk.ac.tees.L1087591.DatabaseHandler.onCreate(DatabaseHandler.java:76)
01-05 17:24:19.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
01-05 17:24:19.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at uk.ac.tees.L1087591.DatabaseHandler.addWebPage(DatabaseHandler.java:101)
01-05 17:24:19.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at uk.ac.tees.L1087591.Home.onCreate(Home.java:52)
01-05 17:24:19.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-05 17:24:19.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-05 17:24:19.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your create query (executed in DatabaseHandler::onCreate()) is invalid:

```
'CREATE TABLE pages(0 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,url URL,source Source, 0 Date)'
```

It should look something like this:

```
'CREATE TABLE pages(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,url TEXT,source TEXT, INTEGER Date)'
```

You can find [SQLite Datatypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

You have `static final int _id = 0;` in your code. You should provide a String here. You could have traced it down yourself: The SQL Query is not valid, the `0` should not be there.

I suggest replacing the line with

```
static final String _id = "id";
```

There might be other errors, try to find them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  static final int _id = 0;

  static final int date = 0;
```

to

```
  static final int _id = "id";

  static final int date = "date";
```

because table Column name always Create as String instead of Integer

Comment: do you mean static final String_id = "_id";

  static final String date = "date";

Answer (score 1):

The error caused by your SQL statement:

> CREATE TABLE pages(0 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,url URL,source Source, 0
>   Date)

You can't put 0 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Column name should be something that makes sense. If the SQL statement is generated by java code then you should check what produces the 0.